# Why is @Spy Abc abc not able to fetch the instance which is present already?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have junit test case where I have used Spy in the following manner and the 
 Junit fails for the below.

```
@Spy
private Abc abc;
```

But runs successfully for this.

```
@Spy  Abc abc =  new Abc();
```

Can someone explain me why? Also, in this statement
 `@Spy  Abc abc =  new Abc();` 
 is there a creation of a new instance or is it using the existing instance 
 that is `Autowired`.

Comment: That is not what my question is about

Comment: That is not a optimal solution for testing.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `@Spy` annotation, Mockito will wrap an existing instance in a spy object. The `@Spy` annotation works like the following code:

```
Abc spyAbc = Mockito.spy(new Abc());
```

This means, that these two expression will result in the same:

```
@Spy Abc abc = new Abc();
Abc abc = Mockito.spy(new Abc());
```

Following statement will only work when there is a default constructor:

```
@Spy Abc abc;
```

Using spies, the spy object behaves the same like your original implementation (although you can define custom test behaviour using e.g.

```
Mockito.doReturn(1).when(abc).myMethod();
```

In contrast, using mock objects (`Mockito.mock(Abc.class)`), will not provide the same behaviour as your original implementation as its not a real instance of your class.

When you want to spy on spring beans, you have to possible ways:

Use `@SpyBean` (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) like this:

```
@SpyBean
private Abc abc;
```

Or use `@Autowired` and `@Spy` in conjunction

```
@Spy
@Autowired
private Abc abc;
```

Both ways will be working. Please be aware the difference of `when(abc.method()).thenReturn(1);` and `doReturn(1).when(abc).method();`. Only in the first scenario is the `method()` actually called (and only it's return modified). For the second example, the method will not be called. This difference is impotant to know if the method has side effects.

Comment: @Stephen So basically there is no difference between _@Spy
private Abc abc;_ and _@Spy  Abc abc =  new Abc();_ ? If yes, why is the  output different?

Comment: I just saw that I missed the `Autowired` part of your question. What do you mean with that? Can you please show your complete test setup?

Comment: Is this way of writing @Spy private Abc abc not correct then?

Comment: Generally, it works the same (by automatically invoking the default constructor -> default constructor must be present) as stated also here: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Spy.html. I suspect there is something more as test setup/environment as you write "or is it using the existing instance that is Autowired". Can you please share the code?

Comment: My code for which I am writing junit rather say class Xyz has dependency on class Abc and so in class Xyz I have autowired Class Abc' instance abc. I just wanted to know if @Spy Abc abc = new Abc(); spies on existing one or creates new one , that is why I wrote that "or is it using the existing instance that is Autowired"

Comment: I see. Thats an important information. So your class looks like the following:
`class Xyz { @Autowired Abc abc; }`. In that case, `@Spy Abc abc = new Abc()`, these two abc instances will of course differ as `new Abc()` is just a simple constructor invocation.

Comment: How can I fix this problem by just using @Spy
private Abc abc;

Comment: Will try it out.Thanks!